# Elastic4s/Elasticsearch - Is there a way to update a document and also remove fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

My application gets change events for a certain object, and from these events, I build a doc that is used to upsert into elasticsearch:

```
      updateById(
        "index",
        "id"
      ).doc(changeEvent)
        .docAsUpsert(true)
```

The problem is, a change event can be nulling out a field/removing a field in Elasticsearch. Would something like this work? Is there a way to do this in one roundtrip?

```
      updateById(
        "index",
        "id"
      ).doc(changeEvent)
        .docAsUpsert(true)
        .script(
          Script(
            "for (field in params.removeFields) {ctx._source.remove(field)}",
            params = removeMap
          )
        )
        .scriptedUpsert(true)
```

Or do I just need to send one upsert request, and a separate script request that will iterate through the params and remove the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot provide a script and doc at the same time, i.e. you can't do a `docAsUpsert`  and `scriptedUpsert` in the same call.

However, since via `doc` you cannot remove fields, I'd do it simply via script. In the script params you can provide two hashes:

- `changeFields`: all the fields to add or change their value
- `removeFields`: all the fields to remove

The script would then become:

```
ctx._source.putAll(params.changeFields);
for (field in params.removeFields) {ctx._source.remove(field)}
```